# Array to TextView

Tags: java, android, arrays, textview

I create this simple method:

```
private void getCheckedItems() {
int len = mGrid.getCount();
SparseBooleanArray checked = mGrid.getCheckedItemPositions();
List <Integer> numberList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    if (checked.get(i)) {
        Integer item = mNumber.get(i);
        numberList.add(item);
        Integer[] mNumberArray = numberList.toArray(new Integer[numberList.size()]);
        Log.d("Played Number: ", ""+ Arrays.toString(mNumberArray));
    }
  }
```

With this control method such elements were selected from a grid and I do them return.
Now I would like to split the array to put in some `TextView`! How can I do?

Comment: what do you mean under "to split the array" and put it in a TextView ?

Comment: I've for example this array [2,3,45,67], I want to insert this array in 4 TextView

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.toString(mNumberArray)` will give you string like this `[2,3,45,67]` Just remove brackets [] and you will have a string like this `"2,3,45,67"`. Now you can easily split string and get a string array. Set each element of this array to each text view

Answer (score 0):

When you want to insert each value from the list to a single textView and if you have the textViews defined you could do something like this:

```
firstTextView.setText(numberList.get(0));
secondTextView.setText(numberList.get(1)); //and so on
```

If you don't have the textViews defined in your layout xml, you could get the parent layout and insert the textViews there like this:

```
LinearLayout parentLayout = (LienarLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTextBoxesParent);
for(int i = 0; i < numberList.size(); i++){
    TextView t = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    t.setText(numberList.get(i));
    parentLayout.addView(t);
}
```